# How to resolve Error 80072F76 while updating windows phone?

Tags: zune, update

While updating windows phone 7 to 7.5 in Zune I am getting the error below. Can someone please tell me what is wrong, and what the fix would be?

> Can't check for updates right now. Please try again later. An Error has occurred: 80072F76

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has posted a pretty thorough [KB article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-Update-error-80072efe-or-80072f76) that might help. I'm only going to include the high level points. I suggest you read the full article for troubleshooting. Essentially, something is stopping Zune from talking to Microsoft's update server.

> If you receive Windows Update error 80072efe or 80072f76 while
>   checking for updates, it might be caused by a connection interruption
>   between your computer and the Windows Update servers. ... If you still
>   receive this error after checking your Internet connection, it might
>   mean that a program running on your computer is preventing Windows
>   Update Services from accessing the Internet. Programs that might do
>   this include firewalls, antispyware software, web accelerators,
>   Internet security or antivirus programs, or proxy servers.